# bitmap zip (BMZ) image creator or converter

Tags: splash-screen, bitmapimage, image-conversion

i am trying to change the splash screen image while booting toradex colibri t20- from default toradex image to my custom image.

thing is that, only specific type of image format, called as .BMZ can only be used for customizing splash screen.

BMZ- it is a bitmap image in compressed format.

i tried too many image creation tools like format factory, etc. i created a bitmap image and compressed into various formats(gz,tar, 7-zip, zip ,etc) and tried directly and also by renaming the extension to *.BMZ. nothing sort of worked.....

updation can be easily done with the tool provided with colibri t20, the tool detects the bmz image and load directly......

any help is most welcome.........

is there anyway or code to convert the a image of a type to the BMZ format using opencv or matlab...... or is there any software for that......

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it? Because I want to do it. On their website they suggest that IrfanView can be used to do it. But I don't find any compressed bmp options in IrfanView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have also suggested to try compressing a normal bitmap with gzip.
After doing some research however, I found out, that the guys over at toradex.com seem to sell a tool called

"Splash Screen Customizer tool":

> converts an unlimited number of bitmap files to the Bmz format for the cost of 4 Support Hours

(see [Toradex Knowledgebase](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/splash-screen))

They also offer you the possibility to send in your bitmaps and convert them into .BMZ for you:

> Toradex converts one bitmap for 1 Support Hours. (Please send us the bitmap in the correct resolution and with 8BPP)

I don't know for sure if their .BMZ format is the same thing as a compressed bitmap image or not, but I would try to give it a shot compressing multiple bitmaps with 8BPP into a single gz Archive (Is there an animation on the splash screen?). If that does not work, I think the only options you have are giving up on the custom splash screen or paying them money to give you the tool/convert the bitmaps for you.

Comment: thankyou big-AdR, i know that toradex guys offer a premium support. their tools or converting one bmp cost a lot.....is there any way to put a image directly into the default splash screen address location. i could try few binary images or try editing the format with openCV

Answer (score 1):

Toradex BMZ format is not compressed, but a variant of the 256 color BMP format.

A 256 color color table (1024 bytes) starts at offset 51, followed by pixel data. Column order is same as BMP, but row order is reversed -- you need to mirror your custom image horizontally. Image width (long) is at offset 43, height at offset 47.

You can extract the existing splash image using the Update tool, and examine the resulting file and go from there. The header contains similar info as BMP header, and if you keep the same size (width & height) it's all trivial: you can just copy and paste color table and pixel data using a hex editor.